# How to execute a C file through cmd

Tags: c, cmd

In my current example, I have a C file called 'Main.c' which converts and prints US pounds into UK stones/UK pounds/kilos, and the variable US pounds is currently defined by the user's input (scanf). The file itself is executed through Visual Express 2013; however, I want to change this so that I can navigate to the C file and execute the file directly through the commmand prompt (cmd) whiles passing a value to define US pounds.

I understand that this is required in main:

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

And I know how to navigate to the C file through the command prompt:

```
>cd Directory/To/The/File
```

However this is where I get stuck; I don't know how to execute the C file. I have researched into this and found several examples, such as using 'gcc' and 'cc', but the system doesn't recognise these commands. None of the materials that I have found fully explains what exactly I have to do in order to accomplish what I am trying to do; do I have to install something, or am I using the wrong commands, is it possible what I am trying to do, what excactly do I have to do?

Comment: Reasons for thumbs down please?

Comment: People sometimes confuse "asking questions where the answers are obvious to people with some experience" with "showing no research effort". The latter is a good reason to downvote; the former is not. Your question shows some research effort even if there are some mistakes (e.g., `cd` to file doesn't work). I gave you a canceling upvote.

Comment: Right, I get it now, I've corrected it, thanks. I'm ok with downvotes, so as long as the reasons are explained so that I don't make the same mistake twice. It separates those who wants to help from those who just wants to be a pain.

Comment: .c files are not directly executable.  The file needs to be compiled and linked. The resulting linked file can be executed from the cmd line.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I just needed a step by step process to accomplish what I was trying to do: open prompt, redirect to file, compile file, and then execute the EXE file. It was the compile and execute I was stuck on, and the research materials I was finding assumed I knew everything about command prompts, and/or assumed that I had already installed everything that was needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Broadly speaking, you need to do the following:

1. *Compile* the program using a *compiler* to generate an *executable*.
2. *Run* the executable file.

When you "run the program in Visual Studio", it is doing all of those steps for you.

<s>I don't know much about command line compiling in Windows, but I believe `msbuild` is the name of the compiler which Visual Studio uses. Look into that, and you'll see how to compile. Compilation will then generate the executable, which you just type into the command line to run.</s>

EDIT: I found [an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384838.aspx) which suggests that `cl` is a C compiler command available on the command line.

Here is the relevant excerpt:

> 6. At the command prompt, specify the cl command together with the name of your source file—for example, cl simple.c—and press Enter to compile the program. The cl.exe compiler generates an .obj file that contains the compiled code, and then runs the linker to build an executable program that has the name of your source file, but has an .exe file name extension—for example, Simple.exe.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted to do, but I did get something to work by using Visual Studio's command prompt instead, once I figured that out, it was just the case of following the provided link. None of the research materials I found mentioned this, many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. You cannot `cd` to the file, only to the directory. The `cd` command means "change directory".
2. You cannot execute a C file, it's just a text file and your computer doesn't know how to run it. You need to compile it first (this is what Visual Studio does). There should be an EXE file somewhere close, you need to find it. It is the binary, executable, form of your C program which you can run directly from the command line.

Comment: 1. Yeah I know, my cd example was just to illustrate me knowing how to direct myself to the required file through the command prompt.
2. That would make sense, so I need to know how to compile and then execute the required file, .exe in this case.

Comment: @Kurtiss: Check my answer out (http://stackoverflow.com/a/25997118/129655). `msbuild` is a tool that will compile Visual Studio projects. It seems `cl` might be a tool that will compile C files directly.

Comment: Command prompt returns 'cl' is not recognised, looking into it now.